# How to print specific line from the GET request Output

Tags: python-3.x, pycurl

Hi Stackoverflow community, I am just new in Python I hope you can help me.

I've tried many different programs, but I didn't get any results. Here is one:

```
import requests
url ="https://bboxxltd.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/CMS/queue/213/issue"
auth='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(auth))
data = r.json().get('summary')
print(data)

Output: None
```

I wanted to have in the "summary", in this example:
[image]

For example:
Output:

```
summary:REQUEST FOR DATA
```

[image]

Comment: In the attachment it is not clear the structure of the data. The higher level attributes are not visible. Also, is `data`  an Array or an Object?

Comment: Hi Adaemero, thank you for the response.
`data` is Object

Comment: Assuming you can reach the elements of the array correctly, i.e. `i` is correct, then access `summary` via the `fields` key: `print(i['fields']['summary'])`

Comment: @Pynchia Your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

As Pynchia points out,
if you can reach the elements of the array correctly,
i.e. i is correct,
then access `summary` via the `fields` key:

```
print(i['fields']['summary'])
```

Also, please post text rather than images.
Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.
You're asking us to volunteer our time for free to solve your problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.
[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

EDIT

Your question is unclear.

It is straightforward to ask for all the elements it contains:

```
for k, v in i['fields']:
    print(f'The value of {k} is {v}.')
```

In your example, one of those `k` keys will be `'summary'`.

Comment: Hi @J_H,


I edited the code and it works
```data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data['values'][0]['fields']['summary'])```
This almost solve the issue but it only gives 1 output and not that all in the json data.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for in in data`, the `i` variable will take the value of the keys of `data`, one at the time. So normally you would do `data[i]` inside the `for i in data`.

If `id` is a high level attribute of `data`, you can simply do `data['id']` outside the `for` loop. Anyways, this all depends on the structure of the returned `JSON`.

From the screenshot, you are getting:

`KeyError: 'summary'`

Which means that `data` is not an Array but an Object. You need to go down the Object further in order to reach the Array you are looking for. You need to inspect the `data` object; one good way to do this is to call `print(data.keys())`, this way, you'll find the attributes that you can access from `data`, until you get the array you are after.

Once you know the structure of the response

```
# It looks like they array is multiple levels
# inside data, so it may look like this:
issues = data[key1][key2]...[keyn]
for issue in issues:
    if issue['id'] == issue_id:
        ...
```